# React Testing Library: Testing an API call on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dom

I'm writing tests for a React component `Order` that renders a user's order and allows the user to view items on the order by clicking on a "View items" button, which triggers an API call.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton";

import { Customer } from "../../../api/Server";
import capitalise from "../../../util/capitalise";
import renderOrderTime from "../../../util/renderOrderTime";

const Order = props => {
    // Destructure props and details
    const { details, windowWidth, iconHeight, cancelOrder } = props;
    const { id, createdAt, status } = details;

    // Define server
    const Server = Customer.orders;
    
    // Define order cancel icon
    const OrderCancel = (
        <svg className="iconOrderCancel" width={iconHeight} height={iconHeight} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path className="pathOrderCancel" style={{ fill:"#ffffff" }} d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm5 15.538l-3.592-3.548 3.546-3.587-1.416-1.403-3.545 3.589-3.588-3.543-1.405 1.405 3.593 3.552-3.547 3.592 1.405 1.405 3.555-3.596 3.591 3.55 1.403-1.416z"/>
        </svg>
    )

    // Set state and define fetch function
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [fetchItems, setFetchItems] = useState(false);

    const [isLoadingItems, setIsLoadingItems] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const fetchOrderItems = async() => {
        setIsLoadingItems(true);

        try {
            let order = await Server.getOrders(id);
            setItems(order.items);
            setIsLoadingItems(false);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(true);
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (items.length === 0 && fetchItems) fetchOrderItems();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [fetchItems]);

    // Define function to view order items
    const viewItems = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFetchItems(fetchItems ? false : true);

        const items = document.getElementById(`items-${id}`);
        items.classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // RENDERING
    // Order items
    const renderItems = () => {
        // Return error message if error
        if (error) return <p className="error">An error occurred loading order items. Kindly refresh the page and try again.</p>;

        // Return skeleton if loading items
        if (isLoadingItems) return <Skeleton containerTestId="order-items-loading" />;

        // Get total cost of order items
        let total = items.map(({ totalCost }) => totalCost).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

        // Get order items
        let list = items.map(({ productId, name, quantity, totalCost}, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i} className="item" id={`order-${id}-item-${productId}`}>
                    <p className="name">
                        <span>{name}</span><span className="times">&times;</span><span className="quantity">{quantity}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="price">
                        <span className="currency">Ksh</span><span>{totalCost}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            )
        });

        // Return order items
        return (
            <div id={`items-${id}`} className={`items${items.length === 0 ? null : " show"}`} data-testid="order-items">
                {list}
                {
                    items.length === 0 ? null : (
                        <div className="item total" id={`order-${id}-total`}>
                            <p className="name">Total</p>
                            <p className="price">
                                <span className="currency">Ksh</span><span>{total}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    };

    // Component
    return (
        <>
            <div className="order-body">
                <div className="info">
                    <p className="id">#{id}</p>
                    <p className="time">{renderOrderTime(createdAt)}</p>
                    <button className="view-items" onClick={viewItems}>{ fetchItems ? "Hide items" : "View items"}</button>
                    {renderItems()}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="order-footer">
                <p className="status" id={`order-${id}-status`}>{capitalise(status)}</p>
                {status === "pending" ? <button className="cancel-order" onClick={cancelOrder}>{windowWidth > 991 ? "Cancel order" : OrderCancel}</button> : null}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Order;
```

Below are the tests I'm writing for `Order`. I've run into some trouble writing tests on the API call.

```js
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

import Order from "../../../components/Primary/Orders/Order";

import { Customer } from "../../../api/Server";
import { orders } from "../../util/dataMock";

// Define server
const Server = Customer.orders;

// Define tests
describe("Order", () => {
    describe("View items button", () => {
        const mockGetOrders = jest.spyOn(Server, "getOrders");
        beforeEach(() => {
            const { getAllByRole } = render(<Order details={orders[2]} />);
            let button = getAllByRole("button")[0];

            fireEvent.click(button);
        });

        test("triggers API call when clicked", () => {
            expect(mockGetOrders).toBeCalled();
        });

        test("renders loading skeleton during API call", () => {
            let skeleton = screen.getByTestId("order-items-loading");
            expect(skeleton).toBeInTheDocument();
        });

        ///--- PROBLEMATIC TEST ---///
        test("renders error message if API call fails", async() => {
            await act(async() => {
                mockGetOrders.mockRejectedValue("Error: An unknown error occurred. Kindly try again.");
            });

            // let error = await screen.findByText("An error occurred loading order items. Kindly refresh the page and try again.");
            // expect(error).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });

    test("calls cancelOrder when button is clicked", () => {
        const clickMock = jest.fn();

        const { getAllByRole } = render(<Order details={orders[2]} cancelOrder={clickMock} />);
        let button = getAllByRole("button")[1];

        fireEvent.click(button);
        expect(clickMock).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

On the test that I've marked as problematic, I'm expecting the mocked rejected value `Error: An unknown error occurred. Kindly try again.` to be logged to the console, but instead I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')`. This indicates that my mock API call isn't working properly and the component is attempting to act on an array of items it's supposed to receive from the API. How should I fix my test(s) to get the desired result?

Comment: I can see a couple of weird things in your tests, but it's hard to tell why the test case for the unhappy path is failing without seeing the actual `Order` component. Can you include that to your question? Also, `mockRejectedValue` takes an `Error` object, not a string.

Comment: @ivanatias Thanks for the info on `mockRejectedValue`; didn't know that. Just included the `Order` component in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experimenting with a simplified example of your case and it seems the issue is with the use of the `beforeEach` hook in which you render the component and click the button before each test. This is not a good idea when it comes to RTL, in fact, there's an [Eslint rule](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-render-in-setup.md) for this.

In order to avoid repeating yourself on each test, you can use a `setup` function to perform these actions on each one of the tests:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Order from "../../../components/Primary/Orders/Order";

import { Customer } from "../../../api/Server";
import { orders } from "../../util/dataMock";

// Define server
const Server = Customer.orders;

// Setup function
const setup = () => {
  render(<Order details={orders[2]} />);

  const button = screen.getAllByRole("button")[0];
  userEvent.click(button);
}

// Define tests
describe("Order", () => {
    describe("View items button", () => {
        const mockGetOrders = jest.spyOn(Server, "getOrders");
  
        test("triggers API call when clicked", () => {
            setup()
            expect(mockGetOrders).toBeCalled();
        });

        test("renders loading skeleton during API call", async () => {
            setup()
            const skeleton = await screen.findByTestId("order-items-loading");
            expect(skeleton).toBeInTheDocument();
        });

        test("renders error message if API call fails", async () => {
          mockGetOrders.mockRejectedValue(new Error("An unknown error occurred. Kindly try again."));
          setup()

          const error = await screen.findByText("An error occurred loading order items. Kindly refresh the page and try again.");
          expect(error).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });

    test("calls cancelOrder when button is clicked", () => {
        const clickMock = jest.fn();

        render(<Order details={orders[2]} cancelOrder={clickMock} />);
        const button = screen.getAllByRole("button")[1];

        userEvent.click(button);
        expect(clickMock).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

I also made some minor changes like: using `userEvent` instead of `fireEvent`, using `screen` instead of destructuring the query functions from `render`'s result, etc. These changes are all recommended by the creator of the library.

Also, in the `fetchOrderItems` function, you should set the loading flag to `false` in case an exception is thrown.

**Note:** The `act` warning might be coming from tests #1 and #2. This is probably because the test cases are ending before all component's state updates have finished (e.g. the loading state toggling after clicking the fetch button). It's not recommended to use `act` on RTL, instead you can modify these tests and use the `waitForElementToBeRemoved` utility from RTL. This will still satisfy test #2, in which you check for the loading skeleton presence since it will throw anyways if it can't find this loading UI:

```
test("triggers API call when clicked", async () => {
    setup()
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByTestId("order-items-loading"))
    expect(mockGetOrders).toBeCalled();
});

test("renders loading skeleton during API call", async () => {
    setup()
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByTestId("order-items-loading"))
});
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! This is working, but I'm getting the good old `Warning: An update to Order inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)` on the third `View items button` test. Wrapping the first two lines in `act()` throws a `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button"` in the setup function.

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible fix for this warning, please check.